# What is char (*arrs)[rowSize] = malloc(bytesPerTable);

Tags: c

Saw this in an answer to another question:

```
char (*arrs)[rowSize] = malloc(bytesPerTable);
```

What is arrs? / why are there parentheses / what is the description of this declaration?

Comment: Did you ask this question there, in the context? I think if you would, I would have answered :)

Comment: I thought about it but I had already asked one. I should have though because now I have two good answers and have to choose one.

Comment: Note that the better way to write it is: `char (*arrs)[rowSize] = calloc(rows, sizeof *arrs);` This avoids having to duplicate the sizes anywhere (which, if done inconsistently, could lead to dangerous errors from under-allocation) and also avoids the possibilities of arithmetic overflow computing the number of bytes to allocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *a[10]` - This means, `a` is an array of 10 elements and the element type is `int *` Size of variable `a` will be 40 bytes in 32 bit machine or 80 bytes in 64 bit machine.

`int (*a)[10]` - This means, `a` is a pointer variable and its size will be 4 bytes(or 8 bytes), which can hold address of a `int` array of size `10` like below.

```
int (*a)[10] = NULL;
int b[10] = {0};
a = &b;
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is arrs ? what is the description of this declaration?

It's a pointer to an array of `rowSize` `char`s, vastly different from a pointer to a `char`.

> why are there parentheses

Because without them it would be an array of pointers to `char`.